# How to catch another process progressbar running on taskbar using C# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

i have a console application.

From it im launching ABC.exe

**ABC.exe running without GUI but shown in taskbar icon.**

And that taskbar icon have a green progressbar.

> I just want to catch that progressbar on my console application like
> 1% done 2% done etc .
>
> I dont want to show total runtime after process exit.

i want to show live output while running ABC.exe on taskbar.

i dident find any solution for Console application.

Im using .net 2.0 so anybody can help me?

```
i just want to catch live progressbar of that exe (its standalone)
```

i have following code but this does not showing any output on console

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "A.exe", // Type filename here.
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }
        })
        {
            proc.OutputDataReceived += DataReceived;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    // Updates a progress value.
    static void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The e.Data property contains programs output string.
        // Esc-symbol \r means overwriting the current line.
        Console.Write("\rTotal " + GetPercent(e.Data) + " completed.");
    }

    // Gets the percentage from the output string. 
    static string GetPercent(string data)
    {
        // The regular expression that finds a number from a string.
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^\d]|^)\d{1,2}([^\d]|$)");
        Match match = regex.Match(data);
        return match.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible. Windows Explorer provides methods in [`ITaskbarList3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3) for *setting* this information, but provides no way of getting it.

Comment: @madreflection I think that's a bit harsh. Perhaps "not intended to be possible"? I see one suggestion is to hook the COM interface to Taskbar and hook the `SetProgressValue` to catch the setting as it is being made... (though I don't see where anyone has published how to read it already).

Comment: @NetMage: OK... that's fair. Now, is that just a suggestion of something to try, or is there a concrete example showing that it's possible to do that? Unless there's a mechanism provided for hooking the interface, I imagine it would corrupt the process if suddenly someone pressed Alt+F4 on the console app that's hooking it (related to OP's previous question... which perhaps could also be answered by hooking the console host if you wanted to take it equally far). Seems fragile to me.

Comment: Sure, at some level, and with the right permissions, you could manipulate the operating system and the running processes in unexpected (undocumented) ways, and maybe it won't break when an update is released. For OP's purposes, though, I don't think this is going to be anywhere near their zone of proximal development to develop or maintain, and being provided a technique, one still has to be able to maintain it.

Comment: @madreflection : okey. is there any hope to catch external process time left on console app? there is no lines of external process. i tried all solutions but still nothing worked. is ther any small tool that can catch that progressbar of ABC.exe same as time left to exit? i will start that tool if that worked. I need a solution bcoz im closing taskbar for some resone and while running that ABC.exe i dident know when will it complete. means how much time left. some pc uses slow HDD. so time required are different for different machines. Thats why its imp thing to know a right answer for my app.

Comment: Remaining process time is a function of what the process is doing, so unless you have the ability to analyze what that process is doing, have access some memory location holding that process's own estimate of that time, or receive that estimate as output (e.g. stdout) from the process, there's no way to know how much *time* is left, and that's even if you *could* access the progress bar, since progress is not progress per time interval, just like `m` and `m/s` are different units.